# Please confirm/correct this: C++ vs Java

Tags: java, c++

When a user defined class (A) has an Object of another user defined class (B) as one of it's data members, then:

> **In Java:** Actually, only a reference to that instance of B is the data member of A, not the instance of B itself.
>
> **In C++:** The entire instance of B is the data member. No pointers or anything. Just the whole solid instance of B itself unless it's dynamically instantiated in which case, a pointer is the data member.

Is my deduction correct or incorrect? I'm not sure myself if this is 100% correct.

Now, I'm really intrigued by this whole thing. Can you take it one step further and tell me something I missed? I mean, what is the significance of this difference? Does it mean, that the class A in Java occupies less space than the same class A implementation in C++?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking for in 1st place. You may add some code samples for both languages, how that stuff should look like.

Comment: Just while I'm there, no, the Java class doesn't occupies less space. It actually may occupy slightly more due to the extra reference.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are basically correct. The Java class

```
class C{
  D dRef;  // needs to be assigned a valid object reference.
}
```

The dRef is assigned a  *new*ed object reference.

Will be constructed similar to the c++ class

```
class C2
{
  D* dPointer;  // needs to be assigned a valid pointer value.
};
```

The dPointer can be assigned a *new*ed object pointer value.
While the c++ class

```
class C3
{
   D dValue;
};
```

Will contain the entire layout size of D, created when a C3 is created.

The c++ version will likely in both scenarios occupy less space than the java version.  For the java version to be usable, e.g. `cObject.dRef.dMethod()` a D object needs to be created, `new D()`. There will be overhead for both the C object as well as the instance. Garbage collection bookkeeping for instance.
  The c++ variants needs only to store the pointer value in C2 (along with a `new D`). For C3, C3 can be the same size as D.

Comment: Minor point:  In the Java case the object "behind" `dRef` will not exist until explicitly created, whereas, as you suggest, the `dValue` object will be constructed when the C3 object is constructed.